# Type 'Dispatch<any>' is not assignable to type '() => null'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was creating my context for my application and I have this typescript error 'Type 'Dispatch' is not assignable to type '() => null'.ts(2322)', I am something new with typescript and I don't understand the error.

this is my code:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}'),
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  dispatch: ()=>null
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

const AuthReducer = (state:any, action:any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_START":
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: action.playload,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }:any) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);


  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch, //error
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

the error marks me when I want to pass Dispatch in the value of my context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix that error by importing and using the `Dispatch` type from React:

```ts
import {
  // ...
  type Dispatch,
} from 'react';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}'),
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  // Use a type assertion on the line below, like this:
  dispatch: (() => undefined) as Dispatch<any>,
};

// ...
```

You can see that the type of the value of `dispatch` that you get from `useContext` is that type. [Here's a modified version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEwKYDMCGBXANvTAZzgCVVMBjGAGjgqnJlQGEIA7JgDxrhgE8wqOABFghMJhgUAFrWyFUAUXTpUVOQrLJsFVFDgBfOOigQQcAEQNKMCwG4AsAChnFdoXgBJAHKeAKp4AggAyAPoAyn6BfopwALyIznBw8noAXHAAUuEA8t4AdBJQCgAUuBAUmLjhMNCYAOao+Y0wnkwgJQDkqVCdAJRwAD6DcJ0IBv3USXDlmMjAbPUZWLgKU07JeqZQGWx4uOvJ8+KSMhklJQNxAHwpbGjoC6jIA0QiYhJS0gA8mGx813WBkcLicqE4kFgdHc8EC2Bg0lYHHB8AS9EYLHYXBgJR8-iCYUi0UUfRBrhhcDhCK0Oj08TgJQ8klQaT+fFoNmA7FZ-yutwQ00IAHdgF8GZz2Pl+IIBgKNsk6EQhBZgjkAOI+CJREh+CxpaYKuAMGDYKBsRLyw3JHq7faHK3JWbzRYZGBQbCoe0OrbQZZVNYGhXAwOVBSWVUa7wRACqzGYinC4T1geSxtN5rlDutCh2cAlbEKmD4Tq9VqdCyWxn9npTCp9uZWActQZBhtDyojmoAYoFPMFoyRFMnm6nUCazRasykc7bcAda46IHMK37VjWR3WoNsMvnCrgiyXa8Hm+3w+qctHdfqN2mJ5msza4Hs56XDeWXVW16-N9un3aj62CoPDg+DXg6t7mkyTCAQYzjHs44KQvAbhsB4cDRjmSLYgACqYABuwBoPoCQlEgMjALgyAMOaBg8nwfKTtCqHwAA2lBnooB8pzSAAuvSqQ0roUAlFS0iCXotB4gEIRasSpLONMqTKKoVAXAx96LpU1S1FADRNAorTtCUFg9BYtDZHk+QeFAFbAOgfCMjAzL5D0fTyfKBi0GxTlMC5OY8e5CnyhBDKBt8olYSi+S4RABFEbWeFVB6cQIBpVqPuxfkSQuMxLs6laZe+9TfpsW6+nAmX1iVnEnF8tAAPT1fWR6wc21y1gg5GUdRrWGt89URViUUxXFejtfK7nHkAA) of the code that you posted in your question with the changes above in the TypeScript playground.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the application works correctly.